# How many envelopes were used in the scene where Harry receives his Hogwarts letter?

Tags: harry-potter, movie

What I want to know is, how many letters were used when they made the scene of hundreds of letters flying from the chimney. Did they use one? Did they use hundreds?

Comment: Looks like ~30 on screen on the thumbnail.

Answer (score 40):

### One thousand

According to *[Harry Potter - The Unofficial Guide to the Collectibles of Our Favorite Wizard](https://books.google.com/books?id=_BVjDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT167&lpg=PT167&source=bl&ots=pNkVh3CGOo&sig=ACfU3U2GcJT9drb71aj-0rOSGKSvczTN1w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjR4LyshPDnAhUMlXIEHU-nAWAQ6AEwE3oECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)* By Eric Bradley:

> Invitations to Hogwarts have themselves become instant collector's items. Who can forget the fan favorite moment from *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone* film when the owl post inundates the Dursley household with millions of acceptance letters informing Harry of his acceptance into Hogwarts? The scene required actual envelopes, as well as special effects.
>
> Two styles of envelopes were made for production with either a rear wax seal or rear printed seal on a 5-1/2 x 7-1/5-inch envelope. Research from production assistants relating to this prop shows only 1,000 letters were made and re-used and reset for this scene. The values between each can be quite stunning.

Comment: Now I had to look it up, there's one of them on eBay for just under $400. Bargain!

Comment: What does "The values between each can be quite stunning." mean?

Comment: @AakashM: The book is primarily about the collectible value. The wax-sealed envelopes sell for much more than the printed seal ones.

Comment: And presumably there's a lot more of them that are pure CGI, so you can't even buy those.

Comment: @Darrel so you mean they are priceless?! no wonder there's such a difference..... :D